# browser to get machine-id by launching an electron app or similar

Tags: javascript, browser, electron

I want to identify a user by unique machine id across all browsers. So came up with an idea of launching a app which determines the machine-id (like electron using nodejs) and passes back the info to the browser that launched it and use for identifying the user.

I have seen something like this been done on [canyourunit](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri)

Can anyone point me right direction where can i find some info about this kind of approach.

Answer (score 1):

As you would be asking a user to download and execute native code, electron or whatever else, there are several complicated issues to consider.

The obvious first one is that you must consider the user platform (OSX, Windows, Linux...) then, communicating back with the browser directly (which one?) is probably not practical.

Your native application could however send the machine id/fingerprint to your backend so you could identify what web client is what.

This is quite involved, fragile, and even if you only support Windows, will fail in many scenarios (system policies, firewalls, antivirus, proxies, strange network setups...)

All in all, it would seem that you should consider more standard [Device fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) techniques if you only need an ID.